# How properly code search bar in HTML to put in into Chrome custom search engines?

Tags: html, search

Lately I've noticed that my Chrome had saved multiple of custom search engines so I can directly search those websites directly in browser by typing their domain name and hit spacebar. So I assume that it's partly automatic and the website's search input or search result should have been coded properly to be saved as custom search engine URL.
How to do that?

Comment: Goto Settings->SearchEngine . Thre you'll see a box with the text "Search engine used in the address bar Learn more". - The Learn More part is a link. That takes you here: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95426?visit_id=637462976671048544-1035958123&p=settings_omnibox&rd=1

Comment: maybe this is what you're referring to? https://support.google.com/programmable-search/answer/4513903?hl=en

Comment: @enhzflep Thank you but how this answers my question? I've asked how web developer should code the search bar/search input on his site to automatically add it to clients browsers? Because it clearly is automatic process as I didn't add any of custom search engines which I have on my Chrome list.

Comment: @Kristian Thank you but not really. What you have linked is Google search engine making searches inside the website and showing results in Google style. It's not really this thing. We already have our internal search script, as many websites, and would like to be automatically added to Custom Search Engines in Chrome/Firefox etc.

Comment: ```You can customize a lot of your search engine, including:

- Apply your site's look and feel to the search box and results page```

Comment: Thank you Kristian, but it's not that thing.

Comment: so you want to make the search query to be appended into https://mysite/?search=keyword+here ? which site does that? I don't even know it's possible with chrome

Comment: @friedman - Nah mate. The browser comes with several search engines already setup. The automatic part of the process was done before the program was turned into a downloadable installable package. ;)

Comment: No, these are not predefined search engines. Those are just regular websites, stores, shops, libraries, auction services... many others. Chrome clearly has auto added them to Custom Search Engine list so there should be a way to mark search input it properly in HTML to let browser recognize it as inside search of the website.

Comment: @Kristian, yes, exactly. I have dozens of these saved in Chrome. Amazon is the example. Also Ebay, Facebook -- from those which are widely known. But I cannot find anything specific in their HTML code.

Comment: @friedman - I think I understand what you're driving at now. If one looks at the search engines list inside Chrome, they'll see a bunch listed under "Default Search Engines" and then a (probably much larger) bunch under "Other search engines". Interesting question.

Comment: @enhzflep Exactly! :)

Comment: @friedman - Did you see this thread? (I haven't read much of it) There seems to be the chance of an answer in there. https://superuser.com/questions/276069/google-chrome-automatically-adding-websites-to-my-list-of-search-engines (Even if that solution is potentially to look inside the source-code for the extension that prevents their addition)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the most popular solution for this is/was using OpenSearch format.
https://github.com/dewitt/opensearch

This might not be the best/only method since many websites in custom search engines of my Chrome are not using OpenSearch and were added to the list by auto detection. But it is some point of start. Better solution I am still seeking for.

Thank you, @enhzflep for tracking me.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is not original from me, but it is an aggregation/summary of other's answer and comment (original poster credited).

Credit for friedman (previous answer) for mentioning **OpenSearch**.

For defining custom search engine, you need to make XML file in this format:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
  <ShortName>Web Search</ShortName>
  <Description>Use Example.com to search the Web.</Description>
  <Tags>example web</Tags>
  <Contact>admin@example.com</Contact>
  <Url type="application/rss+xml"
       template="http://example.com/?q={searchTerms}&amp;pw={startPage?}&amp;format=rss"/>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

xml format described in https://github.com/dewitt/opensearch/blob/master/opensearch-1-1-draft-6.md#OpenSearch_description_document

then save that file as open-search.xml and insert this tag in html page (like when adding css to a page):

```html
<link rel="search" href="/open-search.xml" title="Search Example.org" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml">
```

When a user browsed to any of your page with that link rel=search in html head element, his/her browser (ex: chrome) will add the page to its custom search engine by itself (unless this behavior is disabled, see https://superuser.com/questions/276069/google-chrome-automatically-adding-websites-to-my-list-of-search-engines credit to enhzflep)

---

Example implementation: github search
[image: github search]

You can see in Chrome setting: open setting and search for "engine"
[image: chrome search engine setting]

Chrome would save its name, keyword, and URL with %s replaced with search query/keyword
[image: github search engine setting]

Inspecting github's html (rendered) source code from chrome's "right click -> view source" shows that github have a link rel=search element
[image: github link rel search elem]

clicking on that link leads to an xml file which define github search engine
[image: github search xml]

```xml
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:moz="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/">
<ShortName>GitHub</ShortName>
<Description>Search GitHub</Description>
<InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
<Image width="16" height="16" type="image/x-icon">https://github.com/favicon.ico</Image>
<Url type="text/html" method="get" template="https://github.com/search?q={searchTerms}&ref=opensearch"/>
<moz:SearchForm>https://github.com/search</moz:SearchForm>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

further comparison shows that the xml define chrome search engine behavior here:
[image: xml define search engine behavior]

Recommended further reading:

- Mozilla MDN docs on OpenSearch https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/OpenSearch
- Quickstart https://solvit.io/ff0865a